# System.IndexOutOfRangeException SQLDataReader

Tags: c#

Olá, estou tentando fazer um código ler oque tem na DataBase do SQL Server, mas estou com este erro:

> ```
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Pontos
>    em  System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
>    em  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>    em  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
> ```

Código:

```
public Usuario InitUsuario(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.pontos = (int)reader["Pontos"];
    return usuario;
}
```

Comment: Não existe uma coluna chamada `Pontos` no que foi retornado pela consulta.

Comment: Mas eu criei a coluna Pontos.

Comment: @Leonardo Araujo, poderia postar as colunas do banco de dados ?

Comment: Talvez a coluna sejá "pontos"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gmmfha

Comment: Manda depurar e ver se tem mesmo, esta tela não quer dizer nada.

Comment: e cade a query ?

Comment: Tipo, eu só criei a tabela e coloquei a coluna, não fiz por query.

Comment: e da onde surgiu esse `SqlDataReader ` ?

Comment: Não entendi, o SqlDatReader é por query?

Comment: Se eu faço uma query da tabela, na query diz que ela é existente

Comment: Manda o código completo da leitura dos dados, por gentileza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro ponto, como é um DataReader, você tem que iterar sobre ele para poder ler algum valor, mesmo que a consulta retorne somente uma linha. Altere seu código para o seguinte:

```
public Usuario InitUsuario(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.pontos = (int)reader["Pontos"];
            return usuario;
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

Não sei em que situação você vai usar reader, mas se for o caso, como é somente um usuário provavelmente que você está lendo, seja melhor usar um DataAdapter, ou já se acostumar com MicroORM's, como o Dapper.